# How to import large sql file in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, import

Trying to import sql file around 8GB using these commands

```
sudo -u postgres psql yourdb -f my_file.sql
sudo -u postgres psql yourdb < my_file.sql
sudo -u postgres cat my_file.sql | psql yourdb

sudo -u postgres psql
\i my_file.sql
```

but all of them returning `out of memory` error message.
Also tried configuration given [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19024/importing-large-quantity-of-data-into-a-postgresql-database)

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Is `psql` throwing the out of memory error, or is the backend server that has the problem?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your reply, what do you mean by backend server?

Comment: Postgres is the (backend) server, psql is the client tool. The exception can either happen on the client when reading the file, or on the backend which is _executing_ the individual SQL statements.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok, got it. psql is returning out of memory error

Comment: So, what is the _exact_ error message?  Please add it to your post.

Answer (score 2):

`psql` generally doesn't need much memory when playing large SQL files, since it doesn't buffer the whole file, only one query at a time, or it uses a `COPY` stream.

The main situation when it may run out of memory is not when importing, but when SELECT'ing a large resultset, especially on 32 bits systems. This situation is generally solved by setting `FETCH_COUNT`.

On import, the dump would need to contain unusually large rows to cause client-side memory issues. The maximum size of a column is 1Gb, so it's theorically possible that it would cause trouble on import, if the database has that kind of contents.

If the system doesn't have enough RAM, maybe you could just add swap space.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'll try to add additional swap space